# How do I get Windows Mobile Device Center to detect Motorola Scanner

Tags: windows-mobile, barcode-scanner, motorola, mobile-devices

I installed Windows Mobile Device Center 64-bit (v.6.1.6965) on my laptop (Windows 7, 64-bit).

When I plugged my Motorola docking station (for hand-held scanners) and docked an MC92N0 scanner, it took a few seconds to recognize the device, but worked fine.

I unplugged my Motorola docking station and plugged in an Intermec docking station to program some scanners, and they too worked fine.

I reverted back to the Motorola docking station, and now it won't recognize the scanners.

I've tried uninstalling, rebooting, and installing Windows Mobile Device Center 3 times already to no avail.

Any answers or thoughts would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into situations where devices stopped working with WMDC/Active Sync.
I've usually found success disabling "Advanced Networking Functionality" on the device.  On your device, tap Start > Settings > Connections > USB to PC > Uncheck "Enable advanced network functionality".

The other thing that usually causes this is the device drivers.  When you plug in the device it tries to install device drivers.  You may end up with a ton of "Windows Mobile Remote Adapter #n" devices showing in Device Manager.  You can clean these up because the device driver will be reinstalled next time you plug in the device.  There is detailed information available about the process [here](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/04/21/getting-rid-of-obsolete-microsoft-windows-mobile-remote-adapter-s/).  If the device driver is failing to install you should see a popup near the clock/system tray area.

If all else fails you can try an unofficial troubleshooting page [here](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/12/17/windows-mobile-device-center-does-not-connect/) and [here](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2013/09/05/windows-mobile-device-center-wmdc-or-activesync-troubleshooting/).

Answer (score 1):

If these steps fail try a different battery in the MC9xxx unit.

Remember...all the actual contacts for communications are on the battery itself.

Was just working with a customer and tried everything....no dice...

Finally we popped a different battery in and Windows finally recognized it.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on Windows 10 (2019) after trying a lot of different things.
What mostly worked was in services, there are 2 services called "Windows Mobile-based device connectivity" and "Windows Mobile-2003-based device connectivity".

[services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ggzy.jpg)

Right click on each service and make sure they start automatically (delayed).
Click the "log on" tab, change the access to be "local system account and enable "Allow service to interact with desktop"
Apply and click ok.

[logon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn7KY.jpg)

Make sure the handheld is docked and the docking station is connected to your computer by USB.

Reboot you computer. N.B. This is the only way to reset the connection if it crashes or stops working.

After logging onto your desktop, give your computer a few minutes to start those services.  When both are running, you will need to open the application "Windows Mobile Device Center" to initiate the connection.  This had be to open for this to work in my case.

[wmc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHCem.jpg)

You should see connected.  Now, windows tends to update itself without your permission so what happens sometimes is the "log on" credentials get reset so you will need to redo them as above.  But for some reason yesterday for me, nothing would connect until I did

> Uncheck "Enable advanced network functionality"

Then it started working again.

Hope this helps others.

UPDATE (Jan 2020):
I had another issue every time I docked the scanner into the cradle, it would detect a USB device but immediately register it as 'unknown device' or sometimes, very rarely, it would list it correctly but disable the device because of a timeout.  My problem here was the computer I was using has USB 3 connections, so I plugged in an old USB hub, connected the dock to that and it hey presto worked again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the other fixes you find on the web, I noticed that the Windows Mobile device will not connect to the Windows Mobile Device Center when I am accessing the Windows machine that runs WMDC through Remote Desktop. Had that problem on Windows 7 and 8.1. The fix for me was to login to the Windows machine first without Remote Desktop after which WMDC will show that the device is connected. Once the connection has been established I could access the machine using Remote Desktop and the Windows Mobile device stayed connected.

Comment: I was about to give up until this post gave me the solution. I have not been able to get it to run on my Windows 10 computer since it was upgraded from 7 (worked fine before), so I used a retired Windows 7 PC, but I was working on it via RDP and nothing worked. Tried with local logon and device connected as it should!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and found a solution.

On my MC92N0 scanner I went into Settings/Control Panel/USBConfig and I had to tap on the "USB Client Mode." It was previously selected to port mode "USB OTG Mode". After doing this I placed it in the doc again and it connected normally\launched Windows Mobile Device Center.

Also fyi you should also be able to find the scanner and access files once you're connected by looking underneath devices in "This PC", similar to how you would access a USB flash drive. I was able to do this on Windows 7 & 8.

Answer (score 0):

I spend a couple of hours trying to make this work for a MC92N0. In my case, I have used windows 10 to configure MC9090s through WDMC with NO issues, however, when attaching an MC92N0 nothing was happening, I could not get the MC92N0 to connect (same results on a windows 7 machine ).

What worked for me was to use a USB hub to connect the cradle to the PC, insert the device into the cradle, then go to the device "control pannel" > "USBconfig" > and then switched the USB modes to "mass storage" and select any of the folders (at this point the windows machine recognized a storage device was attached, but still no WDMC connection) > then I switched the setting back to "ActiveSync Serial" and the WDMC showed a connection!

For reference, my current settings for USB connection are as follows from control pannel on the device:

*"PC Connection"= "Enable direct connections to the desktop computer" is checked and set
to "'USB"

*"USBConfig" = "USB Port Mode" is set to "USB OTG Mode"
"USB Client Mode" is set to "ActiveSync Serial"

Answer (score -1):

I sometimes run into this issues myself.. i just open the WDMC manually then pull the device out of cradle and put it back in and that sometimes fixes the issue..

**EDIT:** Ok i have found a solution and that involves creating a batch file.. WMDC used to open fine for me until i upgraded to Windows 10 now it only does it when it wants to... See [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdupdate/windows-mobile-device-center-fails-to-launch/191e6a44-df8b-4ef3-a772-91d04c299435?auth=1) for details